# chrome extension background execution time limit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm creating a Chrome extension that does a lot of asynchronous and heavy work in the background. It downloads loads of images from the web, converts them, and then saves them into a zip. The time needed to complete all this can be above 1 minute.

I have noticed that sometimes unfortunately the extension doesn't finish the work, and the background page becomes inactive and execution stops. When I have the background page open this never happens - it only happens when it's closed.

I initiate the work in the background script by a message from a content script. It seems that if I provide a 'sendResponse' callback, and in the background indicate that I'm waiting for a response with a return value of 'true', it works:

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
        if (message.action === 'download') {
            downloadAction(data, type).then(r => { 
                console.log('finished');
                sendResponse('success');
            })
        }
        return true;
    })
```

When I don't provide a return of 'true', it doesn't. So is this the proper way to execute long async code in the background, even when I'm not interested in the response? Or is this just a workaround that happens to work?

There seems to be a limit of how long the extension will work in the background when initiated with a message without `return true;` What about initiation with an alarm? Furthermore, is there a limit of how long it will work when I indicate that I'm expecting a response with a `return true;`? Surely it won't let me run the background script indefinitely?

Comment: This is one of the few ways to keep the background script running, it's a documented behavior so you can use it safely. More info: [Persistent background page on demand or an event page that doesn't unload?](//stackoverflow.com/q/37017209)

Comment: As for a time limit on `return true`, there's seemingly none. And I'd say if anything can change in the future it's likely they'll limit CPU budget of the background scripts (which will switch to service workers) but not the idle time when nothing actively runs.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, you're always here to help. I completely forgot about persistent: true, which I could also have used as a last resort, although I understand it's discouraged.